# Mary has 10 hair bows,(...) how many different ways can she give them to her friends?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Mary bought 10 hair bows, all different from each other, and 3 of them
>   are red and the rest are blue. Now, she wants to give them to her best
>   friends, Hannah and Sophie, so that:
>
> - each friend will get the same number of hair bows
> - Hannah will get exactly 2 red hair bows
>
> How many different ways can mary give the bows to her friends?

I did:

- How many bows Hannah gets = $^3C_2*^7C_3$

$^3C_2$ because she has to have 2 red bows, and $^7C_3$ because those are the remaining bows.

- How many bows Sophie gets = $^3C_1*^7C_4$

$^3C_1$ because if Hannah gets 2 of the red bows, then Sophie can only get one and $^7C_4$ because those are the remaining bows

So the result: $$^3C_2*^7C_3*^3C_1*^7C_4$$

But my book says the solution is $^3C_2*^7C_3$

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fulfill the most stringent restriction first. Since Hannah is picky, we tackle her first.

We have to give her 5 total and exactly 2 red bows. There are 
$$
{3}\choose{2}
$$
ways to do this, or $3$. Then we have to give her another 3 from the not red pile, and there are 
$$
{7}\choose{3}
$$
ways to do this. The multiplication rule gives you your result ${{3}\choose2}*{{7}\choose{3}}$, since we have no choice but to give the other girl the remaining 5 bows.

Comment: Right, since the order doesn't matter in this case and the bows Sophie gets depend on which Hannah gets. Thanks

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire Just notice that$ 2C3*3C7=1C3*4C7$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Interesting